# React: Unmount event listener from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my app.js I am mounting event listeners. After several reloads I am getting "warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added".

My code is like so.

```
  let App = React.createClass({

     componentWillMount() {
       ArticleStore.addChangeListener((e) => this.onArticleChange(e));
     },

     componentWillUnmount() {
       ArticleStore.removeChangeListener(e);
     }

   }
```

However, componentWillUnmount never gets called in app.js because it exists on the server and I end up with a lot of event listeners open causing the above error and maxing out my event listener limit.

How can I unmount any event listeners in my app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is called on the server, but `componentDidMount` is not. To prevent leaks, you'll generally want to use `componentDidMount` for event registration.

```
let App = React.createClass({

   componentDidMount() {
     ArticleStore.addChangeListener((e) => this.onArticleChange(e));
   },

   componentWillUnmount() {
     ArticleStore.removeChangeListener(e);
   }

 }
```

Comment: I have moved the event listener to componentDidMount() and is now working perfectly. Thanks.